# What procedure did the UNSC use to enhance Spartan II bones, and material is used to enhance them?

Tags: halo

I remember hearing somewhere that when the Spartan II soldiers were made, they had surgeries done to enhance them. One of those was involving reinforcing the bones. How was this done and what material was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Carbide Ceramic Ossification](https://halo.fandom.com/wiki/SPARTAN-II_augmentation_procedures)

Referenced from [Halo: The Fall of Reach](https://halo.fandom.com/wiki/Halo:_The_Fall_of_Reach), Page 57 (Original), 74 (2010 Edition)

> Advanced material grafting onto skeletal structures to make bones
> virtually unbreakable. Recommended coverage not to exceed 3% total
> bone mass because of significant white blood cell necrosis.

From [Halopedia](https://www.halopedia.org/Project_ASTER):

> The candidate's bones are exposed via surgery or procedurally
> sequential surgeries. An advanced carbide ceramic material is grafted
> onto the skeletal structure to begin assimilation into the upper
> layers of the each individual bone. This results in the bones being
> virtually unbreakable. The coverage of this procedure does not exceed
> 3% total bone mass due to significant white blood cell necrosis:
> effectively, the carbide ceramic can only comprise a thin outer
> "shell" bonded to each bone without interfering with bone
> functionality as organs.

So far as I can tell, the exact materials used are never stated.

Comment: good enough for me